# Prove the Halting Problem is undecidable (using a reduction)

Tags: formal-languages, automata

In Hopcroft, Motwani, and Ullman, "Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation",
2nd edition there is the following problem.

Prove that the halting problem is undecidable.

I assume you make a reduction of the halting language
to the universal language $L_u$, but I do not see it clearly.

At this point we have proven that $L_u$ is recursively enumerable and
not recursive and $L_d$ is not recursively enumerable (the languages
are defined below).

Halting Language
$L_H$ = { (M, w) | M halts when given w as input }

The universal language
$L_u$ = { (M, w) | M is a Turing Machine and w is a string in (0+1)*,
                 such that w belongs to L(M) }

The diagonalization language
$L_d$ = { $w_i$ | $w_i$ does not belong to $L(M_i)$ } where $M_i$ is
the ith turing machine, and $w_i$ is the ith binary string.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: You do indeed want to make a reduction, but it goes the other way. If you reduce $L_H$ to $L_u$, all you've shown is that $L_H$ is *no more complicated than* $L_u$; you want to show that $L_H$ is *at least as complicated as* $L_u$. So you want a recipe for taking a pair $(M, w)$ and spitting out a pair $(\hat{M}, \hat{w})$ such that $w$ is in $L(M)$ iff $\hat{M}(\hat{w})$ halts. Do you see how to get such a thing?

Comment: Also, $L_d$ as you've defined it **is** recursively enumerable . . .

Comment: Oops! Right, $L_d$ should be the set of strings of $w_i$ such that $w_i$ is not in L($M_i$)

Comment: Noah: I do not see how to convert (M, w) into (M', w'), how so?